# How can i set up a windows service to listen to events on a remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-services, events

I have a asp.net web app and a windows service running on separate machines.  How can i enable the windows service subscribe/listen to events raised by the asp.net app on the remote machine?  What methods can i use?

An example of events that can be raised on the asp.net app is a user uploading a file.  Once the upload has completed the windows service should be notified so it can do some work.

It seems that there needs to be a layer in between asp.net and windows service, possibly another windows service or WCF app?  Or plain old polling through a shared database containing the state?

I'm not really sure, hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Create a wcf service and host it in your window service. When your web service receive a file, it will call a method on the windows service (wcf).